# Device Manager for Tizen won't open (0xc000007b)

Tags: java, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-studio

I'm facing a problem with Tizen Studio, my device-manager does not work. At first I had a DLL problem (mscvp120.dll) that I managed to correct. I am now facing a second problem when I launch Device-manager I get this error (0xc000007b). I've already found some topics that talk about it and propose solutions, but I've tried everything nothing works:

- I have installed jdk8 as recommended by the samsung developers.
- I have correctly configured the environment variables for java
- Re-install Tizen Studio
- Re-install Java 8 and JDK 8
- The Device Manager package is correctly installed
- shutdown/start up my computer

Nothing worked. If you have any clues I would be delighted.

Error Message

[image]

Correct installation of java and jdk

[image]

Comment: I am having the same issue with Windows 11 and have followed all of the troubleshooting advice and still no success.

Answer (score 1):

Device Manager in Tizen Studio isn't really necessary. You can just use the device select field instead...

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is fine for connecting to the device, but if the device needs a certificate installed, this new tool does not appear to have the "permit to install applications" feature. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the device manager by running the device-ui-3.0.jar located in the C:\tizen-studio\tools\device-manager\bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your PC name contains space character (Maxime Guenneteau).
It will cause many issue. You can change it (remove space) and retry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, with windows 10  it's impossible or very very very complicated to change the user name, i will create another user with no space and i will re-install tizen and java on it